# Get questions content from Stack Exchange API

Tags: stackexchange-api

I need to get the question/answer content from Stack Overflow site using the username.

I know we are able to retrieve data using the question id, using this API call:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/{id}
```

Is there a method to fetch questions and answered publish by a particular user?

Something like:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/{username}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a note ,
Method you mentioned, will return the user by user id, not question by question id.

You should change it to

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/{id}
```

To

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/{id}
```

Coming back to your question,There is no method available to give you questions/answers by username, what you can give it try is that get id for user first and then try below methods for questions/answers of user respectively.

```
//Questions by user id :
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/{id}/questions?

//Answers by user id
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/{id}/answers?
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1759197/questions?answers=true
```

1759197 should be replaced by the users ID (in this case, that is your ID)